# AJAX 500 using In Place Editor to upload managed_file image

Tags: blocks, panels, files, plugins

I have a plugin that allows the user to upload an image using managed_file to use as a bg image. While using the In-Place editor, I get a Ajax 500 error when trying to upload. I will post my watchdog log below. When trying to edit the same page via admin>structure>pages>content, I am able to do this perfectly fine. It also seems that, after uploading the file in admin>structure>pages>content, I am able to swap this image on this block plugin using the in place editor, but trying to do this initially with the in place editor fails.

Watchdog:

```
a:6:{s:5:"%type";s:9:"Exception";s:8:"@message";s:84:"Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile' is not allowed";s:9:"%function";s:11:"serialize()";s:5:"%file";s:89:"/var/www/my_domain/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Serialization/PhpSerialize.php";s:5:"%line";i:14;s:17:"@backtrace_string";s:4943:"#0 /var/www/my_domain/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Serialization/PhpSerialize.php(14): serialize(Array)
#1 /var/www/my_domain/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/KeyValueStore/DatabaseStorageExpirable.php(81): Drupal\Component\Serialization\PhpSerialize::encode(Array)
#2 /var/www/my_domain/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormCache.php(197): Drupal\Core\KeyValueStore\DatabaseStorageExpirable->setWithExpire('form-DsqsvPhU0k...', Array, 21600)
#3 /var/www/my_domain/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(441): Drupal\Core\Form\FormCache->setCache('form-DsqsvPhU0k...', Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))
#4 /var/www/my_domain/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(419): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->setCache('form-DsqsvPhU0k...', Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))
#5 /var/www/my_domain/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(621): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->rebuildForm('panels_ipe_bloc...', Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState), Array)
#6 /var/www/my_domain/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(314): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->processForm('panels_ipe_bloc...', Array, Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))
#7 /var/www/my_domain/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/FormBuilder.php(212): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->buildForm('panels_ipe_bloc...', Object(Drupal\Core\Form\FormState))
#8 /var/www/my_domain/web/modules/contrib/panels/panels_ipe/src/Controller/PanelsIPEPageController.php(385): Drupal\Core\Form\FormBuilder->getForm('Drupal\\panels_i...', 'Featured FAQ', Object(Drupal\panels\Plugin\DisplayVariant\PanelsDisplayVariant), 'b9459017-7024-4...')
#9 [internal function]: Drupal\panels_ipe\Controller\PanelsIPEPageController->getBlockPluginForm('page_manager', 'home-panels_var...', 'Featured FAQ', 'b9459017-7024-4...')
#10 /var/www/my_domain/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(123): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /var/www/my_domain/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(582): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
#12 /var/www/my_domain/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(124): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext), Object(Closure))
#13 /var/www/my_domain/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(97): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array)
#14 [internal function]: Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
#15 /var/www/my_domain/web/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(153): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#16 /var/www/my_domain/web/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)
#17 /var/www/my_domain/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(57): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#18 /var/www/my_domain/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(47): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#19 /var/www/my_domain/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(99): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#20 /var/www/my_domain/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(78): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#21 /var/www/my_domain/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(47): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#22 /var/www/my_domain/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(50): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#23 /var/www/my_domain/web/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#24 /var/www/my_domain/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(657): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#25 /var/www/my_domain/web/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#26 {main}";}
```

AJAX Error:

```
AjaxError: 
An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 500
Debugging information follows.
Path: /admin/panels_ipe/variant/page_manager/home-panels_variant-0/block_plugins/CTA/block/0b850df7-0e57-4b46-acc7-386dd294ff13/form?element_parents=flipper/front/settings/ablecore_style/background/bg_image/image&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax&ajax_form=1
StatusText: 500 Service unavailable (with message)
ResponseText: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
ajax.js:110:32
```

I was assuming it was related specifically to this issue

> a:6:{s:5:"%type";s:9:"Exception";s:8:"@message";s:84:"Serialization of
>   'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile' is not allowed

And found someone with a similar issue here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45154697/serialization-of-uploadedfile-is-not-allowed

But it was in a non drupal context so I wasn't sure where to go from there. Could the In Place Editor ajax error have to do with the UploadedFile error? And if so how would I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Drupal is trying to cache a form with an attached UploadedFile object in it.

Is your custom Plugin a Block with a file element in it?

In your **blockForm** function try:

```
$form_state->disableCache()
```

## **UPDATE 1**

Based on @Aaron's feedback I updated buildForm to blockForm above.

---

**Note:** Disabling caching for a form does have performance implications.

In general you can disable caching for a form anywhere you create or alter a form. Those functions typically have at least two parameters:

```
@var array &$form
@var \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state
```

Comment: I'm using a module that extends blockform, so i am able to add background images to any block plugin. So many block plugins have these UploadedFile objects.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Aaron. I updated the post based on your experience.